# Coloring osm graph edges in python

Tags: python, graph, openstreetmap, edges

I'm trying to make a map where a certain route, e.g. the edges included in the route, is colored. For now, I have the following code:

```
node_route=[1223724841, 1688813022, 2464466873, 1688813022, 1688813022, 1688813022, 1688813022]
ec = ['w' for u, v, k in G_map.edges(keys=True)] 
for i in range(len(node_route)-1):
    ec = ['r' for u, v, k in G_map.edges(keys=True) if (u==node_route[i] and v==node_route[i+1])]
    
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_map, node_color='r', node_edgecolor='k', node_size=40, node_zorder=3, edge_color=ec, edge_linewidth=1)
```

The list node_rote is the ordered route i would like to color. I start by assigning 'w' to every edge in my graph (G_map). Then i check every pair in my node_route list (index i and i+1) and if the pair is equal to 'u' and 'v' of the graph edges it will be colored with 'r'. The problem is this code returns an empty list.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are re-assigning `ec` each time through the loop, throwing away the earlier value.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you might be better off building a dictionary that maps node id:s to their position in `node_route`. Then loop over `G_map.edges(...)`, looking up the positions of the `u` and `v` nodes in `node_route` using your dictionary, and appending 'r' or 'w' to `ec` depending on whether `pos[u]+1 == pos[v]` or not.